# Check if an application is running with PackageMaker

Tags: macos, packagemaker

Using PackageMaker, how do I check if an application is running and pause the installation if it is?

If it matters, this is not the application I am trying to install that I am checking for since I am installing a plugin.

Comment: Use a preflight shell script for that. You can even display a dialog using `osascript`.